# Gradle JaCoCo plugin - class and method names not clickable in report

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I've created a simple Java project which uses Gradle. I've added some unit tests and integrated JaCoCo plugin to see the code coverage. It all works well, however, in the HTML report I can't click on the class name to see exactly which lines and branches are covered. I have another project which uses Maven and JaCoCo where this functionality works. Is it a limitation of Gradle plugin, or am I doing something wrong? Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
}
```

And here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: Can you try with the latest Gradle version? I believe this has meanwhile been fixed.

Comment: Initially I was building it with Gradle 1.8, now I've updated to Gradle 1.9 and the issue persists. Should I try 1.10-rc-2?

Comment: Please do so. If this doesn't fix it, please report the problem at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Works fine with Gradle 1.10-rc-2! Thank you for your help, please create an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are describing appears to be fixed in Gradle 1.10-rc-2.

Comment: Just fyi Pete. I have used the same situation with Gradle 1.6 and it was working. Just trying to say that may be jacocoTestReport needs correct configuration settings for sourceDirectories, classDirectories, additionalSourceDirs, additionalClassDirs.