# Jacoco - Generating report, but not linking source files - Incorrect package structure? - FIXED

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

FIXED - Sorted it! Turns out, when you're adding package declarations to your file, you shouldn't add in a full path (ie src/main/java/com/company/app). Instead you should just package by whatever directories you have within app for example. So in a util directory, you can literally just have it as package util. Then Jacoco properly read the source files and calculated coverage

---

I've been having problems using Jacoco to generate good code coverage reports for a little project I've written.

Mostly following the example, I've read here https://www.baeldung.com/jacoco - I've configured my pom to have the prepare-agent goal and the report goal. This all seems to work in that I'm generating a `site/jacoco` directory with html files for different classes and so on.

However when I generate the report and look at `index.html` within jacoco, I get the error `source file x was not found during generation of report`. This is for all my files.

[Link to error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr1h5.png)

Interestingly, when I tried adding a file called `Foo.java` in the root level of my project (`com/philsfakecompany/chessapp`) without any package declarations or management, and then ran the report - Jacoco linked it correctly, generated the source file, and calculated code coverage. This makes me suspect I'm doing something wrong with my packaging structure/directory structure.

In a `GameManager.java` files, I have given it the package `com.philsfakecompany.chessapp`, which just reflects the project directory structure - and I see that same structure maintained in the generated binaries in the target folder. Within jacoco, it comes out as a few files within`site/jacoco/com.philsfakecompany.chessapp`.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I assumed you were supposed to add package declarations to all files and that they essentially reflect the directory structure. I could get around this problem by removing any package structure and having all my files in root - but that feels horrible.

I've had a poke around other stack overflow posts -and the most relevant I found was
[JaCoCo Not Generating Coverage Reports based on Source File - Method names not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829414/jacoco-not-generating-coverage-reports-based-on-source-file-method-names-not-c).
However it doesn't solve my problem. I have line numbers in the generated pages- so I know its not a problem with classes not being compiled with debug information. I suspect it might be a problem with packages, but I think I'm following the example they set in that post

I'll add my POM below as well in case any errors are coming from there.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be super grateful!

Comment: Sorted it! Turns out, when you're adding package declarations to your file, you shouldn't add in a full path (ie src/main/java/com/company/app). Instead you should just package by whatever directories you have within `app` for example. So in a util directory, you can literally just have it as package util.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"when you're adding package declarations to your file"` and `"you should just package by whatever directories you have within app"`??  What configuration did you use to solve the problem?