# Source file was not found during generation of report

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco, multi-module

help me understand what's wrong, please.
I've worked with multi-module project and faced one problem.
My architecture look like this:

```
proj1
-src
--main
---java
----com.myProj.myApi
-----directories containing .java files

... // same proj2 and proj3

rootProject src
-main
--java
---com.myProj.myApi
----Application.java
-test
--test .java files
```

In the root gradle, I have defined the following:

1. Variable with project names.
2. After testing useTestNG(), the jacocoTestReport() task starts.
3. Inside the jacocoTestReport(), I have determined which java files need to be loaded and checked.
   My root build.gradle:

```
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile).all { options.encoding = 'UTF-8'  }
  }

  group = 'com.myProj.myApi'
  version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  apply plugin: 'java-library'

  jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
  }

  def otherProjects = [':proj1', ':proj2', ':proj3']

test {
  useTestNG()
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

otherProjects.each {
  evaluationDependsOn it
}

jacocoTestReport {
  FileTree sourceTree = files().getAsFileTree()
  FileTree classTree = files().getAsFileTree()

  otherProjects.each {
    sourceTree += project(it).sourceSets.main.allJava
    classTree += project(it).sourceSets.main.output.asFileTree
  }

  sourceTree = sourceTree.matching {
    exclude '**/nonTestedClass.java'
  }

  classTree = classTree.matching {
    exclude '**/nonTestedClass.class'
  }

  getAdditionalSourceDirs().setFrom(sourceTree)
  getAdditionalClassDirs().setFrom(classTree)
  reports {
    html.enabled = true
    xml.enabled = true
    csv.enabled = false
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation project(':proj1')
  implementation project(':proj2')
  implementation project(':proj3')
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'org.testng:testng'
}
```

Gradle version is 7.0.1. Java 11.
I've looked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829414/jacoco-not-generating-coverage-reports-based-on-source-file-method-names-not-c), but my paths for each project are correct as you can see in architecture.

[image]

**EDIT 1**
I found that in each subproject, the build directories contain class files only for those java files that are in a specific subproject. Maybe this is the problem? Maybe I need to send all class files to the root build directory or not?
P.S. build.gradle of subprojects do not contain any jacoco settings.

**EDIT 2**
I've added print for getAdditional...Dirs() and learned that all paths are correct and found.
Also terminal gives me this info:

```
> Task :jacocoTestReport
[ant:jacocoReport] Classes in bundle 'myProj' do no match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
```

But it's very strange, because when i've added this code

```
println(JavaVersion.current())
```

I've got this result: Java Version: 11. It's correct version of my Java:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it when I changed work with files. I've deleted all code from 'jacocoTestReport {' to 'reports {' (non include) and insert this:

```
  for (proj in otherProjects) {
    sourceSets project(module).sourceSets.main
  }
```

I don't understand why getAdditionalSourceDirs() and getAdditionalClassDirs() aren't working. Or, most likely, i don't know difference between these 2 methods of interaction with files. If you know, you can comment under this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `com.myProj.myApi` is a single directory? whereas it should be 3 directories nested into each other `com` / `myProj` / `myApi`

Comment: And there is. By the way, above I under the heading EDIT indicated a possible reason, am I right?

Comment: You're mixing many unrelated things together - "Classes in bundle 'myProj' do no match with execution data" has nothing to do with with original "Source file was not found" and with version of Java.

Comment: And IMO there is no https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in your description, so unlikely that somebody will be able to blindly guess what is wrong in your case. Have a look at 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_jvm_multi_project_with_code_coverage.html
and compare your setup with following minimal-reproducible-example
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/4e03f54df0ddfdc9eca268cb38bc6034d25e38ff/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/jvm-multi-project-with-code-coverage

Comment: I got the same result. This is strange because when I use Intellij IDEA Run> Show Code Coverage> test.exec, the IDE toolkit shows me the highlight code.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. I was using some plugins which were generating source java files in the `build` folder. The coverage report (which included % coverage) for these source files generated in build folder was coming up but the exact source code file with coverage was not getting generated.
I was getting the error: `source file com/abc/xyz/aop/LoggingAspect.java was not found during generation of report`.

I found the solution to my issue in JaCoCo's FAQ page: https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html
`Source files must be properly supplied at report generation time. I.e. specified source folders must be the direct parent of the folders that define the Java packages.`

**The sourceSet that I added for the generated code in build directory was not the direct parent of the Java package**.

Project structure:

```
project-root
- build
-- generated
--- sources
---- com/abc/xyz ('com.abc.xyz' Java package)

- src/main/java
-- com/abc/xyz ('com.abc.xyz' Java package)

-build.gradle
```

The initial incorrect `build.gradle` file to add generated code to sourceSets:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs += 'build/generated/sources/com'
    }
  }
  test {
    java {
      srcDirs += 'build/generated/test-sources/com'
    }
  }
}
```

**I configured the source directory for generated code to `build/generated/sources` instead of `build/generated/sources/com` and it worked.**

Because `build/generated/sources` is a direct parent of `com.abc.xyz` but `build/generated/sources/com` isn't as it includes the path `com` in it.